# Can we Release Version 0.2. to the AppStore and simultaneously keep already active Beta-testing for Version 0.3. alive

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, versioning, testflight, beta-testing

I know it sounds like kind of the wrong workflow but we need to make that work.

- We have external Beta-Testers actively testing Version 0.3 of our App.
- we have NO Version in the AppStore until now
- we Need to publish a Version to the AppStore for sale WITHOUT killing the Beta-testing for our testers on Version 0.3

Is it correct that if we publish Version 0.2 to the AppStore for sale and the review process will be Succesful, testing in 0.3 will not be disturbed and testers can keep on testing 0.3 as nothing happened?

Apple-docs at least state that ONLY earlier Versions of the App will be affected and will be removed (and therefore testing will stop on this Versions)

> When builds become unavailable
>
> Before your app becomes Ready for Sale, the Prerelease pane lists all
>   builds for all prerelease versions you have uploaded. After the app
>   becomes Ready for Sale, some of the builds will be removed from the
>   pane:
>
> ```
> The build USED IN THE APP is removed from Prerelease, as are all other builds in the SAME PRERELEASE  version
> ```
>
> All builds in EARLIER prerelease versions are also removed from
>   Prerelease.

The for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user can continue testing 0.3

> all other builds in the SAME PRERELEASE  version

means all builds with the same marketing version (0.2 here).

And as far as I am concerned you workflow seems more than correct : Releasing version N while N+1 is being tested.

Answer (score 0):

you can always create another version and upload it for review